# NPM install Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm i @angular/cli -g
```

**npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '**
I currently cannot use npm install anywhere.

1. Tried to use npm clear cache --force
2. Tried to downgrade npm( npm install npm@4.1.6) is giving the exact same error
3. Unistalled node, deleted folders npm and npm-cache from Users\username\Appdata\Roaming, Reinstalled node.

I am using  node v11.4.0 and npm v6.4.1

Comment: This error means that your JSON has a syntax error. Check your package.json and package-lock.json

Comment: Try with adminstrator in cmd.

Comment: @dwjohnston, which package-json are you refering to. I am getting this particular error wherever I use the command. Is there a specific json you are refering to.

Comment: @SachinShah, I tried, running as adminstrator also not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Resetting the registry back to https://registry.npmjs.org/ worked for me.

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well .

Comment: I tried all the proposed solutions from other pages such this one [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990) and none of them worked. But finally this one worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. I had to delete the package-lock.json